# Obtain the subtracted area of 2 images via Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I can subtract 2 images by the following codes:

```
import cv2

original = cv2.imread('image1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
tiled = cv2.imread('image2.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
subtract = cv2.subtract(tiled, original)

cv2.imwrite('subtract.png', subtract)
```

However, how can I obtain the area (maybe in form of array of pixels, or shapes) that results in black (i.e. after subtraction, the pixel is black color)?

I can only think of looping through each pixel of an image to check whether the pixel value equals to an array of zeros.

*Ultimately, I want to change those pixels in black color after subtraction to be transparent.*

Comment: check cv2.inRange

Comment: I tried `cv2.inRange(img, black, black)` where `black = np.array([0, 0, 0], np.uint8)`. With this approach, the black area in the original graphics will also be selected.

Comment: try cv2.absdiff instead of cv2.subtract. This is most likely a problem with your matrix types.

Comment: instead of using loop, maybe you could use bitwise comparison with black image.

Comment: @nick the results of `cv2.absdiff` and `cv2.subtract` are the same.